# cheap Arduino recommendations

Tags: arduino

i am creating a light strip and was wanting to use an Arduino for it. as i was looking at the price tags i figured i would come here and ask for recommendations.

i need something with similar functions to an Arduino Uno, is able to be battery powered, and is cheaper.
i would use a name-brand Arduino for this project but that would be too expensive so please avoid just saying "Just Use A Normal Arduino!"

Thanks!

Comment: How many IOs do you need? The Digispark is reasonably cheap and simple

Comment: @towe i need about 8 GPIO. 3-4 of them need to be analog (For RGB)